# SelectedValue of a new item in Combobox

Tags: ajax, combobox

I have been using the Ajax Combo box and I bind it from database, and all works fine. Later I used the selected value to get the results using Linq.
But whenever I add a new item in the same, that is combo box, I get the selected text as the selected value, so in that case it creates an exception.
What can be the better way of getting the selected value of the new item so that I can just by pass the exception.

Should I give it a temporary Id?

How to do that?

```
Cmbx.DataSource = ScmsFeeBLObj.Mthod();
Cmbx.DataTextField = "Text";
Cmbx.DataValueField = "Id";
Cmbx.DataBind();

protected void Cmbx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String Id = Cmbx.SelectedValue.ToString();
        obj = ScmsFeeBLObj.FillData(Id);
    }
```

**Back Code (In DAL):**

```
public ELClass FillData(String Id)
    {
        Int32 ID= Convert.ToInt32(Id);
        var q = (from schedules in context.FeeSchedules
                 where schedules .ScheduleId == ID
                 select schedules );
        return q.SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: can you put some more code?

Comment: When we add a new item we get "New" value as a selected value, which creates an exception when I use Linq to get the results from the database, as there is no conversion from string to int for this New.

Comment: What about posting some more code?